# Compare number of rows in different tables group by date

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to connect MySQL query to a PHP or JSON line chart (Number of records per Date) with multiple lines (Topic1, Topic2).

Example of Topic1 MySQL table:

```
 created_at           |  text    
------------------------------------------------
 2015-07-21 10:10:40  |  hello this is a text
 2015-07-23 06:12:45  |  text number 2
 2015-07-23 10:12:45  |  text number 3
 2015-07-24 10:17:50  |  blah blah
```

Example of Topic2 MySQL table:

```
 created_at           |  text    
-----------------------------------------------------
 2015-07-21 10:13:23  |  hello this is another text
 2015-07-22 06:12:25  |  text number 4
 2015-07-23 10:13:09  |  text number 5
 2015-07-24 12:58:27  |  blah blah blah
```

So I was thinking to create a new table to display the chart.

Expected output of new table (table_count) for chart:

```
 Date        |  Topic1    | Topic2    
-----------------------------------------------------
 2015-07-21  |    1       |    1
 2015-07-22  |   NULL     |    1
 2015-07-23  |    2       |    1
 2015-07-24  |    1       |    1
```

I have tried this MySQL query

```
INSERT INTO table_count (Date, Topic1)
SELECT date_format(created_at,'%y-%m-%d') AS Date , COUNT(*)  
FROM Topic1
GROUP BY Date;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table_count (Date, Topic2)
SELECT date_format(created_at,'%y-%m-%d') AS Date , COUNT(*)  
FROM Topic2
GROUP BY Date;
```

But the output would be

```
 Date        |  Topic1    | Topic2    
-----------------------------------------------------
 2015-07-21  |    1       |   NULL
 2015-07-23  |    2       |   NULL
 2015-07-24  |    1       |   NULL
 2015-07-21  |   NULL     |    1
 2015-07-22  |   NULL     |    1
 2015-07-23  |   NULL     |    1
 2015-07-24  |   NULL     |    1
```

Thank you in advance!

**Edit (Solved):**

```
SELECT a.Date, IFNULL(a.Count,'0') as Topic1, IFNULL(b.Count,'0') as Topic2
FROM
(SELECT date_format(created_at, '%y-%m-%d') as Date, COUNT(*) as Count FROM Topic1 GROUP BY Date) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT date_format(created_at, '%y-%m-%d') as Date, COUNT(*) as Count FROM Topic2 GROUP BY Date) b
ON a.Date = b.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the sample where you join results from both tables:

```
select a.Date, a.Count as Topic1, b.Count as Topic2
from
    (select date_format(created_at, '%y-%m-%d') as Date, COUNT(*) as Count
        from Topic1 group by Date) a
    outer join
    (select date_format(created_at, '%y-%m-%d') as Date, COUNT(*) as Count
        from Topic2 group by Date) b
    on a.Date = b.Date
```

EDIT: added outer join to get rows with NULL in one topic.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried to execute the query there is no row returned.

Comment: That was indeed due to wrong name in "on" clause. Try query with outer join to get the nulls. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: I could not execute the edited query with outer join as MySQL states "Syntax Error: 'outer' (outer) is not valid input at this position